# AppleScript to control sound output balance preference

Tags: applescript, audio, preferences

When I pair my Bluetooth headphones with my Mac Pro, the sound balance drifts kind of randomly, not always, but sometimes.

To fix this problem, I've made an app with AppleScript as follows:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    
    tell application "System Events"
        launch
        tell process "System Preferences" to tell slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 to set value to 0.5
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences"
        quit
    end tell
 end tell
```

It's supposed to reset the sound balance if I run the app.

For some reason, however, it leads to an error message as follows:

`Can't get [[class tabg]] 1 of windows 1 of [[class prcs]] "System Preferences" of application "System Events". Invalid Index. (-1719)`

Why am I getting this? How should I fix the code?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: It's Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a timing issue in that the target **UI element** is not yet available to be manipulated.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Ouput tab of the Sound pane.

tell application "System Preferences" to ¬
    reveal anchor "output" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"

--  # Wait for the target UI element to be available to minulate.       
--  # Then minulate the target UI element.

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        set i to 0
        repeat until exists slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
            delay 0.1
            set i to i + 1
            if i ≥ 30 then return
        end repeat
        set the value of slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 to 0.5
    end tell
    delay 0.2
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

---

**Notes:**

The is the basic format I use for all **UI Scripting** of **System Preferences** and I have added comments to the code as why I have coded it in this manner.

Note that as coded it does not show the **UI** of **System Preferences** as it just does not need to be shown in this use case.

Assuming **System Preferences** is closed when the *example* **AppleScript** *code* is run, all you will see as far as **System Preferences** goes is the **System Preferences** icon bounce on the **Dock** for a moment.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>